# How can I view older Google API quota data?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-developers-console

I am on the quotas page for a project for a specific API. I can see the graph for the usage for the last 30 days. Is it possible to see older data?
(Example for quota page: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/static_maps_backend/quotas?project=[project-name])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it's currently not possible to see older usage information in the API console.